# Automatically copy Selected Text in Android and Use it

Tags: android, text, selection

I am trying to make an app which will automatically store data which is selected by user for example user is browsing web and he selects a sentence , when he selects the text I want to copy it automatically and on shaking the device I want to store it in Database. I have handled the shaking of the phone and i is working fine with hard coded values. Now I am stuck in automatically copying the selected text. Can any body help me if it is possible and how can I get the selected text.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html is a good start.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am stuck when some text is select how can I manage that? How will I know some text in xyz application is selected and will then ask clipboard to copy selected text.

Comment: it's been awhile since i used `ClipboardManager`, but it holds `ClipData` which *might* be an instanceof String (and might not!). if it is a String then grab it from `ClipData` and use it. (again, i might be mis-remembering)

Comment: also, on my device i get a small popup that has `Copy`, `Cut`, and `Paste`. that's how my app was able to get my String into `ClipData`. You could do that with a button click as well, i guess.

Comment: I think I didnt make my point clear let me try again
I want my app to trigger a function when the user shakes the phone after selecting any text. I want to know pragmatically that user has selected some text. is that possible?

Comment: in the `TextView` class i see `getSelectionStart()` and `getSelectionEnd()` that might work. note that i've never used them myself. good luck.